# Keycloak returns Resource Not Found when creating policies

Tags: ldap, authorization, keycloak, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create client policies in my realm, but whenever I submit them for creation, Keycloak returns a "Resource Not Found" error. I've already tested in a container without any custom config and it returns the same error.

Keycloak version: 10.0.0

[image]

https://gfycat.com/elegantphysicalemeraldtreeskink

Answer (score 0):

Changed image version to 10.0.1 and it's working now.